# How to configure JDBC, Tomcat for Eclipse IDE on my Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mysql, eclipse, openjdk, jdk, tomcat

I got an eclipse IDE on my client's machine. He needs to configure JDBC, and Tomcat on this  IDE to use for his Java projects. Kindly help. He got mysql installed right now.

Comment: A previous post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356616/configuring-tomcat-6-with-eclipse-in-ubuntu

Comment: I need a clear description

Comment: Here is the official page on installing tomcat.. https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/tomcat.html

Answer (score 2):

This does not answer the question.

The main issue here is not that you have to install the mysql connector, that is straight forward, the problem is that ubuntu does not install tomcat-jdbc.jar..  from what I have seen, has no repository containing it.  So you cannot apt-get package to fix this issue.
tomcat-jdbc.jar is REQUIRED to do database pooling, what any SERIOUS web app should be using.
tomcat-jdbc.jar is INCLUDED with tomcat7 as downloaded directly...

So no official way to include it.  This is a worry to developers.

Made me uninstall tomcat7 and use a hand installed version as to make sure dependencies are good.

This is a bug in the Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 0):

JDBC (Java DataBase Connector) is nothing else then a simple jar file for the certain database and required to be visible only (included to the java execution classpath) for your java appication. So you can put it where you like, but it's a good idea to put it in your's application root or lib folder.

You can download the latest driver for mysql here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html

A good video tutorial about how to install Tomcat on Eclipse IDE you can find here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9DCOA4tF_M